# Open events in VBA not working?

Tags: vba, excel

I coded certain events to occur when a workbook is opened and they were all working fine yesterday, but today, I  noticed that a macro would suddenly send up an error. Basically, I moved a button to another sheet and I thought the error was coming in because of a change to a protected sheet was causing the error. So I added some coding to unprotect the sheet before saving to avoid the error.

Well, that worked but all of a sudden all of my open and right click events in are no longer working. I tried removing the code I added, but the effected events are still not working. Any idea why that started happening?

Initial open event coding:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Sheets("LogDetails").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    If Sheets("1107").Cells(1, 6) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter log number"
        Cells(1, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Cells(1, 6).Activate

    End If



End Sub
```

Worked fine yesterday. I started getting an error in the code that logs changes to the document. Even though this code should have already unprotected the "LogDetails" sheet, I moved the macro to this sheet, so I thought that since this was the active sheet that this code didn't unprotect appropriately, thus causing the error. (The initial error was that I was trying to make a change to a protected sheet and suggested I unprotect the sheet. It was working fine yesterday though.)

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim sSheetName As String
 sSheetName = "1107"
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
 Application.EnableEvents = False
 Sheets("LogDetails").Unprotect
**error hit at this line**
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Target.Address(0, 0) 
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Environ("username")
 Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Now

 Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:D").AutoFit
 Application.EnableEvents = True


 End If
 End Sub
```

I added this to the beforeSave event. I added it here for a reason that made sense at the time (to me) but it has since been deleted. I don't really think it's relevant.

```
If Sheets("LogDetails").Active Then
    Sheets("LogDetails").Deactivate
    End If
```

So I have removed all code that I attempted to add today and my open and right click events are still not working. They aren't event working on another document with similar open events, that I made no changes to. How did I break excel??

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` is application wide. If you have an error after this line and before `Application.EnableEvents = True`, no event will be generated until you execute a `Application.EnableEvents = True` command.

Comment: If you are debugging, just type `Application.EnableEvents = True` in the Execution window.

Comment: You mean to change "Application.EnableEvent = False" to True? Doing that will allow it to complete the code there. Do You mean the immediate window? I'm not really familiar with use this window.

Comment: The immediate toolwindow/pane (Ctrl+G) is your best friend!! Try it today! Type `?2+2` and then hit ENTER - now set a breakpoint (F9) on the `Sheets("LogDetails").Unprotect` line in your code and type `?Target.Address(0, 0)` in the immediate pane when execution stops there - see? ;-)

Comment: I love new friends!! I did as you suggested and it returns the cell where my macro is. This is what I thought was going on. This code looks for changes on any pages that is not LogDetails then it unprotects LogDetails to document changes. I *think* because I moved the macro to the LogDetails page and now I run the macro from there, the bit of code doesn't unprotect the sheet since LogDetails is active?? But I don't know why this is running anyway since there are no changes being made to the sheet that need to be documented. Does that make since?

Comment: When I say macro, I mean the button I inserted to run the macro.

Comment: @MsAgentM Yes, I meant Immediate windows (French interface says Exécution)

Comment: Ok, so this initial issue is fixed.. As in I restarted my computer and now the open events work and I'm back to my original problem. So I think I need to ask a new question.

Comment: Did you try completely closing Excel and restarting it? (and verifying that no excel process was launched?) It should have solved your problem.

Comment: Yes, that corrected my issue of the open events not working. Now I am back to my original issue. I'm researching some fixes but I may need to post another question.